# How to get feedburner origLink from xml source

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, feedburner

```
$data = file_get_contents('xml-file.xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($data);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$url = $elements->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('feedburner:origLink')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

on the other hand, **title, guid, description** work, don't understand why

```
$title = $elements->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

actaully its showing error while fetching the Element name can't be used directly. 
You need to use namespace for `feedburner` which is given below.

```
 <your namespace object in php>  nsfeedburner = "http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0";


$url = $elements->item(0)->getElementsByTagName(nsfeedburner + "origLink")->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Hope this helps